# how to play streaming mp3 messages (uint8 bytes) generated by ROS audio_capture in html WebAudio Api

Tags: websocket, mp3, ros, web-audio-api, audio-capture

I am trying to play streaming mp3 messages (uint8 bytes) generated by ROS audio_capture in html using WebAudio api.

The messages are generated by ROS audio_capture which publishes the mp3 as uint8 bytes. I am grabbing each message and trying to play it in the Web browser using web audio api.

Below is the sample mp3 message:

```
data: [255, 243, 152, 68, 193, 22, 185, 255, 114, 223, 97, 38, 124, 172, 27, 246, 218, 254, 194, 80, 189, 84, 180, 209, 56, 254, 114, 135, 214, 30, 151, 78, 75, 159, 104, 148, 93, 149, 152, 155, 66, 68, 77, 137, 197, 34, 132, 145, 8, 138, 163, 10, 159, 17, 160, 23, 78, 4, 43, 174, 73, 201, 40, 63, 17, 28, 209, 153, 70, 81, 180, 42, 180, 226, 199, 155, 79, 189, 189, 51, 135, 145, 183, 139, 206, 179, 81, 185, 55, 158, 158, 89, 168, 133, 27, 112, 101, 139, 143, 24, 73, 193, 5, 201, 195, 32, 81, 205, 100, 189, 224, 214, 122, 225, 61, 221, 74, 155, 134, 73, 229, 200, 24, 71, 83, 118, 86, 245, 166, 149, 53, 187, 113, 23, 17, 124, 43, 40, 232, 206, 60, 171, 168, 41, 158, 44, 112, 218, 54, 123, 29, 123, 163, 99, 79, 94, 174, 49, 242, 214, 50, 238, 153, 95, 57, 221, 223, 129, 247, 35, 157, 50, 77, 52, 69, 119, 110, 70, 44, 83, 84, 85, 141, 220, 190, 12, 85, 81, 24, 2, 122, 169, 36, 150, 238, 0, 232, 21, 230, 42, 96, 104, 226, 58, 78, 169, 244, 172, 228, 145, 76, 173, 170, 129, 62, 173, 50, 73, 91, 246, 17, 201, 6, 36, 101, 70, 69, 42, 146, 182, 124, 54, 11, 164, 78, 43, 44, 166, 188, 233, 96, 170, 171, 123, 66, 202, 107, 172, 152, 150, 143, 54, 68, 85, 70, 15, 3, 147, 69, 205, 25, 64, 210, 175, 185, 48, 165, 166, 94, 101, 85, 3, 36, 66, 99, 232, 153, 102, 196, 75, 152, 133, 79, 206, 202, 226, 158, 140, 158, 69, 221, 1, 70, 217, 193, 204, 138, 48, 138, 76, 127, 88, 211, 52, 173, 249, 85, 63, 201, 204, 210, 86, 42, 28, 135, 255, 187, 122, 220, 51, 27, 45, 238, 104, 73, 101, 165, 63, 190, 110, 102, 247, 66, 218, 251, 79, 131, 181, 44, 92, 167, 133, 160, 155, 228, 102, 119, 151, 159, 105, 85, 235, 145, 60, 252, 125, 120, 73, 211, 98]
```

Raw data received from audio source before base64 decoding mentioned below, let me know if its not a valid mp3 format.

```
//OYRM0VceN1L2EjfqzL/sJWwwydElS3xJYcJKpYaLXtfXvddaz6w5T+8w8/p6du6oWOCT6zoDp+zx9GnhKa8j0MGzMgZEs3bs5Z+x0InDcmNueXnI5J+eVwfp9emvuEZ2Oy2mNa7P3YYm+eK90yG6ktKsaInN/SpHvPlpxWo92+lBsUa9GHQagbEyziEbey/u8pi28oYYYW6B5mt0jZk1Ob7IFLsMIKSlOT3W2WXmcPS1Mhc0KIUiDkQ4IelkEbh6+OfQ/2llZ0karuqgLm5UZmFiYKwpE4wJMp0skT+cEmnaGUBIwvvpdXGyMCIEEEJAuQRTlJZtZoV0xGzMpG5tM+6ae6QKo5vTV2cmIBtiktmtOaqyQgxndQE/iCQQLCgpB8HVYUHBB0ldKDBBtGQKKkMKijjKVRoZIC/TYqVBS48IOBsoQsTiGpCygM3vbJNoZglxABBQerkwRDi7ipiISrDbitccaj
```

I am holding it in javascript array initially, then converting it to ArrayBuffer, then passing ArrayBuffer to decodeAudioData(), where i'm getting below error

```
Error in promise : Unable to decode Audio Data
```

Below is code:

```
function playByteArray(byteArray) {

    var arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(byteArray.length);
    var bufferView = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    for (i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
      bufferView[i] = byteArray[i];
    }

    context.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer, function(buffer) {
        buf = buffer;
        play();
    });
}

// Play the loaded file
function play() {
    // Create a source node from the buffer
    var source = context.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = buf;
    // Connect to the final output node (the speakers)
    source.connect(context.destination);
    // Play immediately
    source.start(0);
}
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

Your chunk of audio data probably isn't complete.  In any case, you should consider using MediaSource Extensions for this task.  That way, you can stream from the source and let the browser handle the rest.

Comment: if the chunk is not complete, do i need to buffer the chunks from websocket ? then manually find the mp3 headers and mp3 data to find complete mp3 frame ??, i'm looking through MediaStream extensions, but not finding way to read from websockets..

Comment: @Mahesh If you use MediaSource extensions, you don't need to buffer.  There isn't going to be a built-in method for reading from WebSockets, you need to write that part.  MSE doesn't care how you get your data.